# How to achieve two bonus points for tile placement in Garum

Tags: scoring

In Garum, each brine tank (*cetarium*) is divided into four spaces, one of which is a 'joker' space (probably better translated as 'wild' but the English rules I have says 'joker').

If you cover the joker space with an unmatching tile, you get one victory point.
If you cover the joker space with "the very same species", you get two victory points.

For the jokers that have just one of the four species, it seems that you need to cover the species with the matching species in the same orientation / position for two points.  So if the joker is a yellow squid in the upper, right, you need to place your tile that has a yellow squid so that the squid covers the upper right of the square.  But it could be that you just need to cover it with any tile that has a yellow squid (since not all the tiles do).

And for the jokers that have all four species, I am unsure of what is required for two points.  In order of increasing stringency...

Is it sufficient to place any tile with all four species on the square, in any orientation?

Or do you need to have a tile with all four species *in the same arrangement* as is shown on the joker, since there are multiple possible spatial arrangements (all of the jokers on the board have yellow diagonal to blue, but not all tiles with all four species have this arrangement).

Or do you not only need all four species in the correct arrangement, but then to also orient the tile in the same orientation as the space on the board?